# XSLT for-each loop inside another for each loop

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I would like to change source.xml into destination.xml using xslt but my code is not working. Kindly help

source.xml

```
<Programme>
  <SubjectList>
    <Subject>Maths</Subject>
    <Subject>Science</Subject>
    <Subject>History</Subject>
    <Subject>Language</Subject>
  </SubjectList>

  <StudentList>
    <Student>
      <Name>Jack</Name>
      <Class>5</Class>
      <Subjects>
        <Course>Maths</Course>
        <Course>Language</Course>
      </Subjects>
    </Student> 
    <Student>
      <Name>John</Name>
      <Class>4</Class>
      <Subjects>
        <Course>Maths</Course>
        <Course>Science</Course>
      </Subjects>
    </Student>
    <Student>
      <Name>Anna</Name>
      <Class>4</Class>
      <Subjects>
        <Course>Science</Course>
        <Course>History</Course>
      </Subjects>
    </Student>

    <Student>
      <Name>Tana</Name>
      <Class>5</Class>
      <Subjects>
        <Course>History</Course>
        <Course>Language</Course>
      </Subjects>
    </Student>
  </StudentList>
</Programme>
```

destination.xml

```
<ProgramList> 
  <Subject>
    <title>Maths</title>
    <Students>
      <Name>Jack</Name>
      <Name>John</Name>
    <Students>
  </Subject>

  <Subject>
    <title>Science</title>
    <Students>
      <Name>John</Name>
      <Name>Anna</Name>
    <Students>
  </Subject>

  <Subject>
    <title>History</title>
    <Students>
      <Name>Anna</Name>
      <Name>Tana</Name>
    <Students>
  </Subject>

  <Subject>
    <title>Language</title>
    <Students>
      <Name>Jack</Name>
      <Name>Tana</Name>
    <Students>
  </Subject> 
</ProgramList>
```

This is my xslt but it is not working, I am very much new to xslt, kindly help.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<subjects>
    <xsl:for-each select="SubjectList/Subject">
      <xsl:variable name="var1" select="."/>
      <subject>
      <title><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></title>
        <xsl:for-each select="StudentList/Student">
            <xsl:variable name="student" select="."/>
            <xsl:for-each select="Subjects/Course">     
            <xsl:variable  name="var2">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:variable>             
                <xsl:if  test= "$var2=$var1">
                <student>
                    <name><xsl:value-of select="$student/Name"/></name>
                    <class><xsl:value-of select="$student/Class"/></class>
                </student>
                </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <subject>
    <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</subjects>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Not working how? In general, XSLT is not like BASIC, where you loop over things with a FOR loop. Set up templates to handle elements, and let XSLT do the looping, that's what it does for a living. Also, indent your code properly, otherwise you and everyone else looking it will pull their hair out.

Answer (score 1):

The context for the path expression `StudentList/Student` is a Subject element, but your Subject elements have no `StudentList` child. You need to go up a couple of levels first: `../../StudentList/Student`. But better, for this kind of problem, read about `xsl:key` and the `key()` function.

Answer (score 1):

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:key name="NameOfTheKey" match="Student" use="Subjects/Course" />
<xsl:template match="/">

```
<ProgramList> 
     
    <xsl:for-each select="Programme/SubjectList/Subject">
    
        <Subject>
        
            <xsl:variable name="title" select="."/>
            
            <title>
                <xsl:value-of select= "$title"/>
            </title>
            
            <Student>
            
            <xsl:for-each select="key('NameOfTheKey', $title)">
                <fromRate>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Name"></xsl:value-of>
                </fromRate>
            </xsl:for-each>
            
            </Student>
            
        </Subject>
        
    </xsl:for-each>
    
</ProgramList>
```

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).